# MYSQL Update Table if Record Exists

Tags: mysql

Ok so I have a table called `cities` with columns `id,city,state,county,zip_code,url`

Then I have a second table called `us_url` with columns: `id, url, city, state`

The `cities` table has a unique key for `city` and `state` to prevent duplicates (So if I import new records, if the city + state combo already exists, skip it).

Right now, the `us_url` is just temporary. I want to copy the data from that table to the `cities` table. So if the `city` & `state` combination doesn't exist in `cities`, insert the new record from the `us_url` table. If it does exist, update the `cities.url` column with the `us_url.url` value.

I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO cities (id, city, state, county, zip_code, url) 
            VALUES(,us_url.city,us_url.state,,url) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=VALUES(url);
```

But that gave me a syntax error and I'm not even sure if that is right.

I hope that makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are too many `,` in VALUES ... `VALUES(us_url.city,us_url.state,url)`. Also,`on duplicate key update`  skips on the first duplicate key, so if you want to filter by a combination column, you would have to create that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into cities (id,city, state,url) (select id,city,state,url from us_url) on duplicate key update url=VALUES(url);
```

should do the trick:

```
mysql> select * from cities;
+------+------+-------+---------+----------+------+
| id   | city | state | country | zip_code | url  |
+------+------+-------+---------+----------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 3     | 4       | 5        | 6    |
+------+------+-------+---------+----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from us_url;
+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | url  | city | state |
+------+------+------+-------+
| 1    | 10   | 2    | 3     |
| 2    | 11   | 3    | 4     |
+------+------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into cities (id,city, state,url) (select id,city,state,url from us_url) on duplicate key update url=VALUES(url);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from cities;
+------+------+-------+---------+----------+------+
| id   | city | state | country | zip_code | url  |
+------+------+-------+---------+----------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 3     | 4       | 5        | 10   |
| 2    | 3    | 4     | NULL    | NULL     | 11   |
+------+------+-------+---------+----------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Close! So yours pretty much just added the URLS starting from the first column, whether it matched the city or not. Using yours, here is what I ended up with that worked: `INSERT INTO cities (city,state,url) (select city,state,url from us_url) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=VALUES(url); `